# AOP skip non-visible classes

Tags: java, spring-aop, spring-social

I am attempting to execute advice at every method call where its possible.  For example, all non final, non enum, and visible classes.

Is there any filter that i can use to skip over the non-visible classes as i am able to do with enums and final classes?  See code below.

```
"execution(* org.springframework.social..*(..)) && !within(is(EnumType)) && !within(is(FinalType))"
```

Is there any filter such as is(EnumType) and is(FinalType) that i can use to exclude non-visible

Comment: What do you mean by non-visible classes?

Comment: Do you use  AspectJ or AOP alliance Spring implementation?

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.social.SocialWebAutoConfiguration$SecurityContextUserIdSource]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null.      How can i skip over the private inner classes?

Comment: !within(class$innerClass) does not work?

Comment: @fg78nc no, it produces an.  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: class$innerClass [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

Comment: You have to hardcode your class and inner class for example
`!execution(* org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.social.SocialWebAutoC‌​onfiguration$Securit‌​yContextUserIdSource‌(..))`
or `!within(org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.social.SocialWebAutoC‌​onfiguration$Securit‌​yContextUserIdSource‌)`

Comment: @fg78nc I wanted a way to automatically exclude non-visible classes.  Instead of manually adding entries.

Comment: I guess there is no way to achieve that. You might create separate pointcut and just combine it whenever you would like to exclude particular inner class.

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope I am using Spring AOP.  I am using the spring-boot-starter-aop

Comment: What about !execution(* *$*(..)) ?

Comment: @Ali Experiencing the similar problem, did you find out the solution?

Comment: I tried doing the above it didn't work for me.